# Xcode integration script for jazzy, the doc generator for Swift projects

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any script available to integrate jazzy, https://github.com/realm/jazzy
with XCode?

I am looking for something similar to appledoc's XCode integration script
https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/blob/master/XcodeIntegrationScript.markdown

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import your PATH so it can find gems, then use the same command line you would in Terminal. For instance, just added this as a script phase in an Aggregate target named "Documentation" to the noted project:

```
PATH=$(bash -l -c 'echo $PATH')

jazzy --clean --author "Alex Curylo" --author_url "http://www.alexcurylo.com" --module PoseGallery --min-acl private --readme ../README.md --github_url "https://github.com/alexcurylo/swift-pose-gallery"
```

Comment: This makes it go in infinite loop since jazzy executes xcodebuild and which in turn invokes this again.